# In Livewire can I update a variable instead of writing to the database in a listener method when using $emitUp?

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I've set up a modal for creating a new House. Within this modal is a section for editing Rooms.

What I want to do is create a way for users to change details (name, description) of each of the rooms without anything getting written to the database until the save button for the whole modal is clicked.

**views/livewire/houses/createHouse.blade.php**

```
<div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">
            <form>
                <div class="w-1/2 pr-4">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <label for="input1">Address1:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter Address" wire:model.defer="address1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <label for="input2">Town:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Enter Town" wire:model.defer="town">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-1/2">
                        <h3 class="mb-2">Rooms</h3>
                        @foreach ($rooms as $key => $room)
                            @livewire('room-show', [$room])
                        @endforeach
                    
                    <span>
                        <button wire:click.prevent="store()" type="button">
                        Save
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**views/livewire/rooms/room.blade.php**

```
 <div>
        <input type="text" wire:keydown="$emitUp('roomUpdated', '{{ $room->id }}', 'name', $event.target.value"
            id="roomName" wire:model.defer="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" wire:keydown="$emitUp('roomUpdated', '{{ $room->id }}', 'description', $event.target.value" id="roomDesc" wire:model.defer="name" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
```

**http/Livewire/Houses.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\House;
use App\Models\Room;
use Livewire\Component;

class Houses extends Component
{
    public $houses, $address1, $town;
    public $isOpen = 0;
    protected $listeners = ['roomUpdated' => 'updateRoom'];
    
    public function render()
    {
        $this->houses = House::all();
        return view('livewire.houses.houses');
    }

   
    public function updateRoom($id, $field, $value)
    {
        //Update the name and description for the room
        foreach ($this->rooms as $key=>$room) {
          if ($room->id == $id){
            $this->rooms[$key][$field] = $value;
            break;
          }
        }
    }

public function store()
{
    // dd($this->rooms); //--- THIS DOESN'T SHOW THE UPDATED NAME & DESCRIPTION ---//

    //Update the house details
    House::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->house_id], [
        'address1' => $this->address1,
        'town' => $this->town
    ]);

    //delete all rooms for this house
    Room::where('house_id',$this->house_id)->delete();

    //re-add all rooms for this house
    foreach($this->rooms as $room){
        Room::updateOrCreate(['id' => $room->id], [
            'house_id' => $this->house_id,
            'name' => $room->name,
        ]); 
    }

    session()->flash('message', $this->house_id ? 'House Updated Successfully.' : 'House Created Successfully.');
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way for me to use $emitUp on each of the room fields so that it updates a variable without updating the database?

EDIT: I've now updated to Livewire v3. But I still don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I would suggest you either convert that Room component into a Blade-component rather than a Livewire one, that way it'll be the same Livewire component, but you can still extract your view into a separate one. Alternatively, Livewire v3 has support for updating a parent from a child, https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/understanding-nesting#updating-the-parent

Comment: I've upgraded to Livewire v3, but it doesn't look like it actually provides a way to do what I'm after.

Comment: I'm happy to convert the Room component into a blade component. But the problem remains that I can't access the input value (room name) from within the parent House store() method.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are unable to access the input values (room name and description) from within the parent House `store()` method.

In your current code, the input values are stored in each `Room` [Livewire component](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components), which emits an event every time there is a change (via keydown). The parent `Houses` component listens to these events with the `updateRoom` method. However, in the `updateRoom` method, the changes are not being saved anywhere persistently.

I suppose it is the main reason you are not seeing the updated values in the `store()` method: they are being lost after the `updateRoom` method finishes running.

A possible solution would be to be stored persistently in the `Houses` component, so they can be accessed later in the `store()` method.
That means initializing a `$rooms` property in the `Houses` component and updating this property in the `updateRoom` method.

With these modifications, whenever a room's details are updated and the '`roomUpdated`' event is emitted, the parent component's `$rooms` property gets updated. Then, when the `store()` method is called, the `$rooms` property contains all the updated room details, so you can access the input values in `store()`.

Your `views/livewire/houses/createHouse.blade.php` remains unchanged.

In `views/livewire/rooms/room.blade.php`, emit an event when the input field loses focus (i.e., when you click outside of it).

```php
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:blur="$dispatch('roomUpdated', { id: '{{ $room->id }}', field: 'name', value: $event.target.value })" 
        id="roomName" wire:model.defer="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" wire:blur="$dispatch('roomUpdated', { id: '{{ $room->id }}', field: 'description', value: $event.target.value })" 
        id="roomDesc" wire:model.defer="description" placeholder="Description">
</div>
```

The `wire:blur` event listener is used to trigger the dispatch of the `roomUpdated` event when a user finishes editing a room's details (i.e., when the input field loses focus). This is done using the [Livewire V3 `$dispatch` method](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#dispatching-events), which [replaces the old `emit()` or `dispatchBrowserEvent`](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#events).
That way, the `Houses` parent component can catch this event, denoted by the `#[On('roomUpdated')]` attribute, and update its `$rooms` property accordingly. The event name and relevant parameters are passed with `$dispatch`. This communication allows the state of the room's details to be tracked without saving them to the database until the final confirmation from the user.

`wire:keydown` (as in your original code) may cause the event to be emitted too frequently, which could affect performance. Emitting the event on `wire:blur` instead ensures the event is only emitted when the user finishes their edits. That is generally more efficient and gives the desired result in your case.

That assumes that each room component has access to the `$key` of the room, which is its index in the `$rooms` array in the parent `Houses` component.

Without this change, the parent component would not receive the updated room details, and thus would not be able to store them for later access in the `store()` method.

But in `http/Livewire/Houses.php`, do initialize the `$rooms` property, listen to the `roomUpdated` event, and update the `$rooms` array whenever that event is triggered.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\House;
use App\Models\Room;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\On;

class Houses extends Component
{
    public $houses, $address1, $town, $rooms;
    public $isOpen = 0;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->houses = House::all();

        if($this->house_id){
            $house = House::find($this->house_id);
            $this->rooms = $house->rooms->toArray();  // fetch related rooms
        } else {
            $this->rooms = [];  // for a new house, start with an empty list of rooms
        }

        return view('livewire.houses.houses');
    }

    #[On('roomUpdated')]
    public function updateRoom($params)
    {
        //Update the name and description for the room
        $this->rooms[$params['id']][$params['field']] = $params['value'];
    }

    public function store()
    {
        // dd($this->rooms); //--- THAT SHOULD NOW SHOW THE UPDATED NAME & DESCRIPTION ---//

        // Update the house details
        House::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->house_id], [
            'address1' => $this->address1,
            'town' => $this->town
        ]);

        // Delete all rooms for this house
        Room::where('house_id',$this->house_id)->delete();

        // Re-add all rooms for this house
        foreach($this->rooms as $room){
            Room::updateOrCreate(['id' => $room->id], [
                'house_id' => $this->house_id,
                'name' => $room['name'],
                'description' => $room['description'],
            ]); 
        }

        session()->flash('message', $this->house_id ? 'House Updated Successfully.' : 'House Created Successfully.');
    }
}
```

In the `updateRoom` function, the `$rooms` array is being directly manipulated using `$this->rooms[$params['id']][$params['field']] = $params['value'];` line. This line of code directly changes the specific room's field (either '`name`' or '`description`') in the `$rooms` array held by the `Houses` component.

---

If your dispatch code looks something like `this.$wire.dispatch('roomUpdated', roomId, 'name', e.target.value);`, then the `updateRoom` method should take in three parameters directly `($id, $field, and $value)` rather than an array of parameters.

```js
#[On('roomUpdated')]
public function updateRoom(int $id, string $field, string $value)
{
    //Update the name and description for the room
    foreach ($this->rooms as $key=>$room) {
        if ($room->id == $id){
            $this->rooms[$key][$field] = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
    $this->skipRender();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when I click away from the input box: `Alpine Expression Error: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Expression: "$wire.$dispatch('roomUpdated', ['id' => $room->id, 'field' => 'name', 'value' => $event.target.value])"`

Comment: @Urbycoz I suspect I used the wrong syntax on `views/livewire/rooms/room.blade.php` (mixed Blade and JavaScript). I have edited that code.

Comment: Yeah that looks like it's getting further- thanks. The `UpdateRoom` method doesn't seem to fire when I use `#[On('roomUpdated')]`. It fires when I use the old eventlistener syntax (i.e. `protected $listeners = ['roomUpdated' => 'updateRoom'];`) but I don't think the parameters are getting passed because I get the following error: `Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $params ]] in class App\Livewire\Houses`

Comment: @Urbycoz The event data might be getting passed as individual parameters instead of an array.  I have edited the answer to illustrate the change in `UpdateRoom `.

Comment: Yes!! I had to stick a `$this->skipRender();` in the `UpdateRoom` method but it seems to be working now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Urbycoz I have edited the answer to include `$this->skipRender();`. Let me know if anything else is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public $roomsData = [];

public function updateRoom($id, $field, $value)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($id, $this->roomsData)) {
        // If not, create a new one with default values
        $this->roomsData[$id] = [
            'name' => '',
            'description' => '',
        ];
    }

    // Update
    $this->roomsData[$id][$field] = $value;
}
```

---

the in `store()` method

```
foreach($this->rooms as $room){
    if (array_key_exists($room->id, $this->roomsData)) {
        $changes = $this->roomsData[$room->id];
        $room->name = $changes['name'];
        $room->description = $changes['description'];
    }
    
    Room::updateOrCreate(['id' => $room->id], [
        'house_id' => $this->house_id,
        'name' => $room->name,
        'description' => $room->description,
    ]); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The `$this->roomsData` array gets reset every time `updateRoom` is called. So only the most recent value is retained in the `store` method. (i.e. If I change the room name then the description and press save, only the description is kept- the name is reset to the original value)